# Does Microsoft provide any automation tool to test REST APIs?

Tags: automated-testing

I am looking for a tool using which I can do automated testing of REST APIs. I was going through SOAPUI. But as our clients prefer Microsoft products, I would like to know if there are any Microsoft API Automation tools. Any help will be great!

Comment: Do you care if you need to write code?  Do you want it to do it all for you after you press a button?  Do you just want something to make your testing a little faster?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.I do not mind writing code to certain extend. Anyways I will have to write some code to handle our security framework as it is a customized security framework. Also for some test cases, request URL, header and body can be formed only based on the response of previous call. And for this case also, I will have to do some sort scripting. And I am looking for tool in which I can do these kind of customization.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio Load Testing with Web Tests does what you are asking for.  You can use the GUI interface to create web tests, or convert them to coded web tests if they are too complex, or you just prefer that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms182594.aspx‎

The biggest hurdle to using Visual Studio Load Testing is that you need to have a Visual Studio Ultimate license which is relatively expensive.

Comment: Thank you Sam for this nice recommendation. I do have a Visual Studio Ultimate License. But Visual Studio Load Testing needs WebTest. I do not have/want to test the APIs through a Web Application consumer. Instead I need to do the functional testing of stand alone REST API endpoints.

Comment: WebTest allows you to automate any web requests, including REST API web requests.  There is a built in recorder that makes it easy to test requests that are initiated from a web app/page but it is not required to use the tool.  You can create the requests manually through the UI or create them manually through code.  I have used it many times for automating testing of rest services.  With that said, I was very impressed with a non-microsoft library called RestSharp  for automated Rest API testing, but that wasn't what you were asking for in the question :-).

Comment: Hi Sams, I tried the WebTest in VisualStudio PerformanceTest. But it allows only POST and GET. Doesn't it allow PUT and DELETE?

Comment: There are 2 options "Insert request" and "Insert Web Service Request"  The second option allows you to specify put/delete/option. I'm not sure why the first does not allow it.

Comment: A slick trick for testing APIs used by applications is to use Fiddler to capture the calls to the backend server and then export them as WebTests. You can then edit the tests in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

The answer will depend on the type of testing you are doing, but you should just use Visual Studio and write some code to call the API directly. You can also=use the unit test infrastructure it provides, or nunit to write your tests.

The best tool to test an api is code that calls it.